# How can i get the data From FileReader() onload

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am converting excel data to json using XLSX and have to send the received data from onload to other functions. The conversion of excel to json is working just file.

```
 var files = e.target.files;
    var f = files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = e => {
        var data = new Uint8Array(e.target.result);
        var workbook = XLSX.read(data, { type: "array" });
        let sheetName = workbook.SheetNames[0];
       
        console.log(workbook);
        let worksheet = workbook.Sheets[sheetName];
        console.log("insde", XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet));


         console.log(XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet))
        
    };

    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(f);
```

i just want to send  `XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet)` as data in other function
Thank your for your help :) .

Comment: You would pass the other function as a callback or promisify this context.

Comment: um.. u mean a function inside reader.onload  and call that function

Comment: no, I mean you need a pointer to the function you want to pass the `XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet)` data to

Comment: Posted it as an answer

Comment: syr i am new to js but i think i know what u r trying to say i will give it a try thak your

Comment: ohh.. thanks bro it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd either pass back a callback or make this a Promisified function.

```js
const fileToSheet = (file, callback) =>
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = e => {
        const data = new Uint8Array(e.target.result);
        const workbook = XLSX.read(data, { type: "array" });
        const sheetName = workbook.SheetNames[0];
        const worksheet = workbook.Sheets[sheetName];

        callback(XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet));   
    }

    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
}

// elsewhere in your program

const files = e.target.files;
const f = files[0];

fileToSheet(file, console.log);
```

You can easily promisify this, and add error handling in the standard callback format that people usually use for a callback.

Comment: For some one like me fileToSheet(file , console.log); means => fileToSheet(file, result=>console.log(result)); :D :D